# Apache Flume shutdown automaticaly

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I'm using flume 1.8.0, its shutdown automatically, can any one help me on this.

1. Running on JAVA 8
2. JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms4g -Xmx4g" configured in **flume-ng** of flume
3. used following commands to start flume **./bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file ./conf/flume-conf-postgresql.properties --name dfm-topostgres-stream &**

**Log before shutdown**

19 Jan 2018 08:07:48,914 ERROR [PollableSourceRunner-CustomDBFlumeSource-s6] (com.ca.devops.dfm.db.dbcustomsource.CustomDBFlumeSource.process:200)  - Transaction id: DFMSILO620180119130160, - Exception java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
19 Jan 2018 08:07:48,914 INFO  [PollableSourceRunner-CustomDBFlumeSource-s6] (com.ca.devops.dfm.db.dbcustomsource.CustomDBFlumeSource.process:207)  - Transaction id: DFMSILO620180119130160, - Processes is ended
19 Jan 2018 08:12:48,915 INFO  [agent-shutdown-hook] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.stop:84)  - Configuration provider stopping

Comment: following is the log where is start shutdown 31 Jan 2018 05:00:51,815 DEBUG [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:127)  - Checking file:./conf/flume-conf-postgresql.properties for changes
31 Jan 2018 05:01:06,483 INFO  [agent-shutdown-hook] (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.stop:78)  - Stopping lifecycle supervisor 11

Answer (score 0):

Flume will attempt to reload its configuration if it detects changes to the configuration file.

The line you quote in your comment:

`org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:127) - Checking file:./conf/flume-conf-postgresql.properties for changes`

indicates this may be related (the above is logged via a logger.debug() call)

Though, I should add, that if I simply `touch(1)` the config file then I see it log a reload but it does not exit:

`26 Feb 2018 15:16:35,785 INFO  [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:134)  - Reloading configuration file:/etc/opt/flume/conf/flume.conf`

So perhaps whatever is changing the file is introducing an error? If that were the case, you should see another log entry logged as an ERROR, indicating the actual problem.

[PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/d1f24f56ce9714bb3e1edc671da290c75a17dead/flume-ng-node/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/node/PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java#L141):

```
try {
  eventBus.post(getConfiguration());
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.",
      e);
} catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
  LOGGER.error("Failed to start agent because dependencies were not " +
      "found in classpath. Error follows.", e);
} catch (Throwable t) {
  // caught because the caller does not handle or log Throwables
  LOGGER.error("Unhandled error", t);
}
```